# Computing $a^b$ (mod c) where b is a very large number

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I've been asked to compute the value of an expression in the form of $a^b$ (mod $c$), where $a, c$ are prime and $b$ is extremely large. How would I use modular arithmetic to do so? I'm thinking that Fermat's Theorem might be helpful, but not sure how.

Comment: Do you know Euler's Theorem $a^{\phi(c)} \equiv 1 \pmod{c}$ for $\gcd(a,c) = 1$?

Comment: I don't believe we've learned that.

Comment: Ah, $c$ is prime, so you're fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: very common question.

Comment: it's only for prime b that you can't resort to repeated exponentiation without addition.